# Profile C++ programm based on wall clock time with intel Vtune amplifier

Tags: c++, linux, profiler, intel-vtune

I've just started using intel VTune Amplifier XE and looks like by default only cpu-time measures. Is it possible to setup VTune to get results based on wall clock time (real time)?
Actually my goal is to get hotspots from disk I/O operations.

Comment: Maybe you've seen [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). It finds speedup opportunities, whether I/O or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure I/O of the app in VTune you can use two features. [Locks and Waits Analysis](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/544023) to trace APIs which are blocking you app execution (including I/O API) or dedicated [Disk Input and Output Analysis](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628099) to see if you are blocked on the disk and what APIs in the app are causing that.